# XML_PARSE_HUGE option in rvest

Tags: xml, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am getting an error that says I need to use the XML_PARSE_HUGE option in rvest, but I can't figure out how to use it.  I tried to do a workaround to grab a list of urls from a site with the xml package, but it did not grab the complete list.  I can try to explain what is going on a bit more, but I will just paste the code I am using to see if anyone knows a way that either one could work.

```
url<-"http://www.example-website.com/url-list.html"
list<-read_html(url) %>% xml_nodes("dd a")
```

This option fails at reading the website, and tells me I need to use the XML_PARSE_HUGE option.  I looked around the help documentation, and tried to read a few other answers here, but they didn't help much.  I installed a version of the xml2 package that was supposed to force the option, but that didn't do anything either.  The other option gets the list (in a clumsy way), but doesn't get the full list.

```
htmlTreeParse(url, options= HUGE) %>% xmlRoot -> check
check[[2]] %>% paste %>% strsplit(split='"') -> check2
url.list<-paste(url, check2[[3]][grep(".htm", check2[[3]])], sep="")
```

As I understand it (and this may be wrong), this grabs the html.  I checked and the second one seemed to have all the links I wanted, so I pasted the html as a character, split it on quotations, and looked through the splits for ".htm" to find the links.  This is probably a clumsy way to extract the links I want, but it actually works fine.  The problem with this option is that the htmlTreeParse doesn't actually get the full list (I checked through here, and it stops a bit short of what I wanted).  The rest of the code successfully grabs all of the links that the htmlTreeParse does.

I just started teaching myself web scraping yesterday, so I am sure I am doing a lot of boneheaded things, but any advice that can be given would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using `read_*html*` and then `*xml*_nodes`? Did you try them in two steps to see which is throwing the error?

Comment: Yeah.  I ran just the read_html, and it is giving me the error.

I put the xml nodes up here to show the end goal, but in the code that is actually giving me the error it isn't there.  I'm not sure why but using read_html, then xml_nodes works fine.  I have successfully used it on other websites.

Comment: `?xml2::read_html` says it normalizes html to xml anyway, so it's probably fine, although deprecated, so you might switch to `xml2::xml_find_all` or `rvest::html_nodes` if issues arise.

Comment: As far as the actual issue, can you edit with a URL that raises the error, so it's reproducible? There's likely an option that you can pass to the helper functions through `...`, but it's hard to verify without the error. You might also try out `xml2::read_xml` with `as_html = TRUE`, as it has an `n` argument to set how many bytes to read per iteration if you pass it a URL.